# IdentityServer4 - full logout certain user during login on another client

Tags: identityserver4, logout

During the login operation on the second client (e.g. second browser) I need to perform logout of the same user both on the IS and client (MVC5) application on the first client.
I was trying to perform this following the way described here:
[link](https://damienbod.com/2016/09/16/full-server-logout-with-identityserver4-and-openid-connect-implicit-flow/)

I am not sure if this article describes what I am looking for. Nevertheless it seems like I am using higher nuget version of IS and several things have changed - doesn't work for me.

Maybe someone knows easier way to do so from IS's AccountController?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a combination of reference tokens persisted inside your identity server plus server-side storage for your identity server authentication cookie (the standard middleware supports this) then you have the ability to remove all auth tickets and tokens for a given user quite easily.

Also useful in the case where a user's password or other security related settings change and you want to force all existing sessions to end.